# Plotting a trend graph with data from different data sources in Amazon QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have to upload two CSV data sets to Amazon QuickSight. Basically they are the data of two different test runs. Now I have to plot a trend graph for the avg response times of both the runs. I couldn't see an option in Quicksight to visualize data of two data sources in one graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Quicksight doesn't allow two different data sources on the same visualization.

Since you are using CSVs, you have the option to 'add data' to a CSV data set from the Data Sets page, just look for one of the CSVs data sets, Edit, and Add Data. Then you will be asked to join them, and select what columns from each file you want.

Then you can create visualizations based on the updated data set.

This is how I've been working around the only one data set per visualization when working with CSVs.